# Azure Bing Web Search api , retrieve metadata

Tags: bing, bing-api

There's any way to get meta-data that's shown on bing website on Bing Web Search api?

I mean, extract from api response (title, connections, industry, location) information like is in website:

[image: Search from bing website]

The api response only returns `snippet` info and this meta-data is not returned.

```
{
        "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.1",
        "name": "Foo Bar - Thing - Thing Company | LinkedIn",
        "url": "https://es.linkedin.com/in/foo-bar-041756111",
        "isFamilyFriendly": true,
        "displayUrl": "https://es.linkedin.com/in/foo-bar-041756111",
        "snippet": "Ve el perfil de Foo Bar en LinkedIn, la mayor red profesional del mundo. Foo tiene 2 empleos empleos en su perfil. Ve el perfil completo en LinkedIn y descubre los ...",
        "dateLastCrawled": "2018-05-02T07:20:00.0000000Z",
        "language": "es"
}
```

Comment: can you share your query?

Comment: Ofc @Ronak here is the query used: 

`https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q="foo bar" site:linkedin.com&count=25`

Comment: Ah, yes. It seems Bing Search APIs are not returning metadata. I tried with S1 subscription, which is all-up. The same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information seems that it's not returned by API and there's no parameter to add this information in responses right now, tested on API v7.0.